# Nested classes with Templates c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, nested

I'm trying to implement methods that are in a nested class, that is inside a template, however I'm not able to do that. I'm new at cpp and would like to know if i can implement it in the way I code here, like outside the namespace and the class scope.

```
namespace structures {
template<typename T>
class a {
   public:
      int funca();
      int funcb();
   private:
      class b {
        void funcc();
      }
}

template<typename T>
int a<T>::funca() {
    // method implementation
}

template<typename T>
int a<T>::funcb() {

  // method implementation

}

// HOW DO i IMPLEMENT THE class b METHODS HERE??

template<typename T>
void a<T>::b<T>::funcc(){  
   //Didn't work
}
};
```

Comment: Functions need a return type.

Comment: `a<T>::b` is not a template. It doesn't require a template argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `void a<T>::b::funcc()`:

```
template<typename T>
class a
{
public:
    int funca();
    int funcb();
private:
    class b
    {
        void funcc();
    };
};

template<typename T>
int a<T>::funca()
{
}

template<typename T>
int a<T>::funcb()
{
}

template<typename T>
void a<T>::b::funcc()
{
}
```